# Rare crash by android.support.v7.app.o$a.onClick (SourceFile:293)

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

There following crash report is generated once in a great while:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v7.app.o$a.onClick (SourceFile:293)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6308)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23969)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6823)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1557)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at android.support.v7.app.o$a.onClick (SourceFile:288)
```

The crash report does not indicate anything related to the app.  I am wondering if anyone could shed some light on this?  Which aspect of the app should I look at to find the culprit?  Should I ignore this due to hardware or OS bug?

Comment: I've the same problem. will let you know if i find a solution to this. Which version of support library are you using?

Comment: Thanks, @MatPag  I am using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.4.0'    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'     compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'

Comment: i've found something, i'll post an answer with some input when i have time but i didn't find a proper solution yet. Another question. Are you using `android:onClick` in any of your XML layouts?

Comment: @MatPag Yes, onClick() is used extensively.